# Conditional partial merge of pattern into graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to create a relationship that connects a person to a city -> state -> country without recreating the city/state/country nodes and relationships if they do already exist - so I'd end-up with only one USA node in my graph for example

I start with a person

```
CREATE (p:Person {name:'Omar', Id: 'a'})
RETURN p
```

then I'd like to turn this into an `apoc.do.case` statement with apoc
or turn it into one merge statement using unique the constraint that creates a new node if no node is found or otherwise matches an existing node

```
// first case where the city/state/country all exist
MATCH (locality:Locality{name:"San Diego"})-[:SITUATED_IN]->(adminArea:AdministrativeArea { name: 'California' })-[:SITUATED_IN]->(country:Country { name: 'USA' })
MERGE (p)-[:SITUATED_IN]->(locality)-[:SITUATED_IN]->(adminArea)-[:SITUATED_IN]->(country)
return p

// second case where only state/country exist
MATCH (adminArea:AdministrativeArea { name: 'California' })-[:SITUATED_IN]->(country:Country { name: 'USA' })
MERGE (p)-[:SITUATED_IN]->(locality:Locality{name:"San Diego"})-[:SITUATED_IN]->(adminArea)-[:SITUATED_IN]->(country)
return p

// third case where only country exists
MATCH (country:Country { name: 'USA' })
MERGE (p)-[:SITUATED_IN]->(locality:Locality{name:"San Diego"})-[:SITUATED_IN]->(adminArea:AdministrativeArea { name: 'California' })-[:SITUATED_IN]->(country)
return p

// last case where none of city/state/country exist, so I have to create all nodes + relations
MERGE (p)-[:SITUATED_IN]->(locality:Locality{name:"San Diego"})-[:SITUATED_IN]->(adminArea:AdministrativeArea { name: 'California' })-[:SITUATED_IN]->(country:Country { name: 'USA' })
return p
```

The key here is I only want to end-up with one (California)->(USA). I don't want those nodes & relationships to get duplicated

Answer (score 1):

1. Your queries that use `MATCH` never specify which `Person` you want. Variable names like `p` only exist for the life of a query (and sometimes not even that long). So `p` is unbound in your `MATCH` queries, and can result in your `MERGE` clauses creating empty nodes. You need to add `MATCH (p:Person {Id: 'a'})` to the start of those queries (assuming all people have unique Id values).
2. It should NOT be the responsibility of every single query to ensure that all needed localities exist and are connected correctly -- that is *way too much* complexity and overhead for every query. Instead, you should create the appropriate localities and inter-locality relationships separately -- before you need them. If fact, it should be the responsibility of each query that *creates a locality* to create all the relationships associated with it.
3. A `MERGE` will only not create the specified pattern if *every single thing in the pattern already exists*, so to avoid duplicates a MERGE pattern should have at most 1 thing that might not already exist. So, a `MERGE` pattern should have at most 1 relationship, and if it has a relationship then the 2 end nodes should already be bound (by `MATCH` clauses, for example).

Once the `Locality` nodes and the inter-locality relationships exist, you can add a person like this:

```
MATCH (locality:Locality {name: "San Diego"})
MERGE (p:Person {Id: 'a'}) // create person if needed, specifying a unique identifier
ON CREATE SET p.name = 'Omar'; // set other properties as needed
MERGE (p)-[:SITUATED_IN]->(locality) // create relationship if necessary
```

The above considerations should help you design the code for creating the `Locality` nodes and the inter-locality relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution I used is much simpler, it's a series of merges.

```
match (person:Person {Id: 'Omar'}) // that should be present in the graph
merge (country:Country {name: 'USA'})
merge (state:State {name: 'California'})-[:SITUATED_IN]->(country)
merge (city:City {name: 'Los Angeles'})-[:SITUATED_IN]->(state)
merge (person)-[:SITUATED_IN]->(city)
return person;
```